# can we delete wp_woocommerce_sessions from database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My website is going down every morning ! i have contacted hosting people they said "The reason of suspension here is because the hosting service have exceeded the database limit of 1GB ,As part of our terms and conditions, we need you to make sure you will not go over the limit of 1GB database"

I checked in database i have table name called 'wp_woocommerce_sessions' size of 1.2 Gb

I have no idea that i can delete this table or not , please anyone let me know can i delete this table ? or please also let me know what is the use of this table in my wordpress site

Comment: ´Woocommerce´ sounds like a table containing user sessions for your commerce web page. Woocommerce is not default from Wordpress, so I would look into the plugin on whether or not its ok to clear the table. 
You should never drop a table unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes , thats what i am thinking !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go to WooCommerce > Status > Tools and there is a button there to clear customer sessions. This should remove all sessions from the database.

These should automatically be being cleared. Is WordPres Cron working/enabled on your site? Under WooCommerce > Status, it should have a green checkmark in the first section. If this is not working, it could be part of the problem.

Comment: so it will not cause any problem to my site right ?

Comment: No it will clear all sessions from table. Please try this

Comment: what does this table is for? I just have a error but i can find the place of error