# How to delete wp_woocommerce_sessions from the database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce website, where I am not able to login currently. As the size of the db has been increased. I tried contacting the support team, they told me that a size of a table named "wp_woocommerce_sessions" is too much. I need to delete the following table, to be able to login to my website.

Currently its size is 766MB, which is too much.

There is a similar ticket [Can we delete wp_woocommerce_sessions from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301087/can-we-delete-wp-woocommerce-sessions-from-database)!
But it didn't solved my problem, as I am not able to login to the admin dashboard.

I have also tried running the following query, still no help.

```
DELETE FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name LIKE '_wc_session_%' OR option_name LIKE '_wc_session_expires_%'
```

Any help is appreciated.